# Rechargeable battery datasheet

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, datasheet, charging

[image: How to read battery datasheet?]

Some parameters on the datasheet are a little bit confusing. What does the datasheet mean?

Comment: Which parts do you not understand?

Comment: 5.2 to 5.6 I can't really understand.

Comment: http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf

Comment: under optimal conductivity the cell should power 3.7 volt for a determined load. under similar conditions the storage temperature and time determine the autonomous capacity in time. finally the operating thermal caracteristics speak about its safety. internal resistance is sometimes a must for calculating equivalent power.

Comment: so nominal voltage means in order to charge the battery at least 3.7v is needed? correct me if I am wrong thank you.

Comment: that would be appropiate to say it's internal impedance has different characteristics. it means output may have a small but visible equivalence.

Comment: how about 5.5 max charge voltage what does it mean?

Comment: it's not lead batteries. you can't go beyond 3.7 over the same temperature curve. 5.5v some other have less requirements those are polymer batteries.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i will be using lithium ion battery

Comment: charge is concentrated thus and then wasted in the internal thermal characteristics such as its variable resistace over time. in the opposite, you can find a discharge curve that adapts to your design. using lithium ion right?

Comment: thanks for helping. maybe i need to search more about battery datasheet. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.2 Nominal Voltage 3.7V:  This is the average voltage of the battery over its entire charge/discharge cycle.

5.3 Internal Impedance <=70mohm:  This is (primarily) the ESR of the battery over its entire charge/discharge cycle.  Whether this condition holds over all environmental and charge state conditions should be noted elsewhere on the data sheet.

5.4 Discharge Cut-Off Voltage 3.0V:  If the pack contains a cutoff circuit, it will kick in when the battery pack gets down to 3.0V to prevent overdischarge.  If not, you should include circuitry to ensure it doesn't get discharged past this point.

5.5 Max Charge Voltage 4.2V:  Don't charge it above this voltage.  When charging, you can keep it at 4.2V until the current goes down, but don't try to charge it faster by applying more than 4.2V.

5.6 Standard Charge Current 0.52A:  Since they specify a "standard" and "max," I'm guessing they have two endurance specs, one for limiting charge/discharge current to "standard" and another one with fewer cycles if you (dis)charge it at "max" current.

Note that you may have to keep the voltage under 4.2 until it's largely charged to avoid exceeding the charge current.